# how to convert a list to array in tcl?

Tags: tcl

It may be a trivial question; but I am facing problem to covert a list to array inside a tcl script.

```
set mylist { one two three four five }
```

I need to convert this to array myArr.
One more doubt, Can we use list elements as separate, like I want to use second element of mylist i.e. mylist(1)?

Comment: "arrays" in tcl are what are actually (unordered) associative arrays (what is called "dictionaries" or "hashes" in other languages). There is no point in converting a list to an array, as you can always access any element of a list with `lindex`: `puts [lindex $mylist 1]` for `two` in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At it simplist, you can go through the list and increment an index `i` to set that array's element `myArr($i)`:

```
set i 0
foreach n $mylist {
 set myArr($i) $n
 incr i
}
```

You can then refer to `$myArr(1)`, but for the list you need `[lindex $mylist 1]`.